# Setting the delegate on initialization of object in conforming "header"

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error trying to set the delegate of my ParseController, which is a property on my VC.

```
protocol ParseControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {

var parseController: ParseController! {get set}
//TODO:- Instead of this function, i should use a closure, but couldnt get the sytnax right!
func updateUI()
```

}

```
class ParseController: NSObject {

weak var delegate: ParseControllerDelegate!
var dataArray:[AnyObject]!

init(delegate:ParseControllerDelegate!) {
    self.delegate = delegate
}
```

Then when I try to set this in my VC "header" I get an error.

```
var parseController:ParseController! = ParseController(delegate: self)
```

I am able to set in viewDidLoad with this method, but ideally I would like to set the delegate where it is. The error I get is

> Type 'MainVC -> () -> MainVC!' does not conform to protocol 'ParseControllerDelegate'

MainVC is my viewController.

Things I tried:

- Casting (self as ParseControlleDelegate)
- self()
- self!

Im sure it is something simple, but I can't figure out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
Proper syntax is:

```
lazy var parseController:ParseController = ParseController(delegate: self)
```

*Note: I had to remove the delegate requirement from my protocol, as I got a compiler warning that "lazy" isn't allowed on a protocol requirement, and the delegate requirement was not met once I declared it lazy in my VC.